# Where can I find the rules to play a craftmason?

Tags: world-of-darkness, product-identification, dark-ages-mage

I was looking for a character sheet for *Dark Ages: Mage*, and I saw that there was also a character sheet for playing as a craftmason.

The idea of playing as a technocrat back when the Technocracy was noble appealed to me, but I can't seem to find the rules for it.

In which book are the rules for playing a craftmason written?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rules you want are in the **Dark Ages Mage: Grimoire**, in the appendix. You can find a future update in **Mage: the Sorcerer's Crusade,** along with many of the other crafts that made up the nascent Order of Reason.

Comment: Those rules appear to be for playing those in the modern nights while i am looking for rules on playing them in dark ages.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu So, to be clear, you're looking for a writeup that uses the Dark Ages: Mage rules, with four pillars and the like rather than spheres?

Comment: Yes. I thought that dark ages part in the question made it clear though it seems it hadn't. Entirely my bad.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu No worries. I added the relevant tag, and I'll update my answer.